# Rails error 500 on local mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, I'm a noob with rails... so I just set up rails with RVM and created a new project, and when I try to visit a newly created view I'm getting an error 500.

Heres my setup:

- OSX 10.6.5
- Installed MySQL 64bit
- RVM installed ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8 (no other rails or ruby except for the system ruby) `rvm install 1.8.7`, `rvm use --create 1.8.7@rails2`, `gem install rails -v=2.3.8`
- Passenger with Apache `gem install passenger`, `rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module`
- Passenger preference pane
- Turned on websharing

I then proceeded to setup a rails project in my development folder called testapp, added it in the passenger preference pane, and then ran `script/generate controller Say`, defined an action hello, and then created a view in the app/view/say folder called hello.

Now I'm getting a 500 error when visiting myapp.local/say/hello, what am i doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

I checked the logs and also tried running using WEBrick instead of passenger and apache.  I got thrown back the same errors.  I don't think I should post the entire log, should I?  But the first error is

> no such file to load -- sqlite3

I have not yet setup a db, I was going to use mysql, but I didn't want to install it since I'm not using models yet.  Is it a requirement?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

So I installed the mysql gem with `gem install mysql -- --include=/usr/local/lib` (not sure if this is right).  I then created a rails app with `rails -d mysql myapp`.  And set the password in the database.yml.  I'm getting a new error now:

> Unknown database 'myapp_development'

So I have to create a database.  Why am I being forced to create a db at all?

Comment: Try checking what's in the log/development.log to see if there are any clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you need to install sqlite even if you're not using models yet - Rails checks to make sure whatever is specified in database.yml is actually there to use.

Comment: interesting... so why isn't that in any of the tutorials haha! Well, I don't want sqlite so I installed the mysql gem (already have mysql installed) and tried running this again and it still didn't work.  According to the tutorial I'm watching, he didn't make any modifications to the yml file before creating that simple controller and view.  Shouldn't this work? How do I setup rails to always use mysql instead of sqlite anyway?

Comment: It's not too hard to modify database.yml to use a mysql adapter instead of sqlite. If you want to have rails generate a new application using mysql for you, use the command 'rails -d mysql myapp'

Comment: Ok, so first of all, thanks for all that :-), I now created a new project using mysql automatically, good to know how.  But it still didn't work.  I now have this error in the log though Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO), nice to see progress!  But whats going on here?

Comment: Have you set up your mysql database correctly? Try logging in via the command line to see if you can actually log in as root.

Comment: Oh, you already set up a password for root? Did you change the database.yml to reflect this? It looks like the rails application is trying to access root without using a password (using password: NO).

Comment: I don't understand why I'm being forced to create a db to set up a project that doesn't need one?  I have set the password via the database.yml, but now I'm getting the error "Unknown database 'myapp_development'"

Comment: That does seem strange. I've never used Rails for a project that doesn't need any database access - I'm curious, what kind of application are you building that needs Rails but has no persistent storage?

Comment: I'm not haha, im a noob and I'm just trying to get started with rails.  In my tutorial the guy doesn't set up the db until 3 chapters on!  So its interesting as to why I'm being forced to create a db when I only want to create a simple controller and view to follow along.  Although this is good learning hehe, but I'd like to figure out the cause..

Comment: Haha gotcha. I just quickly created a test rails app on my end, but it doesn't seem like its complaining about any database errors (and I haven't created/migrated anything yet). I'll let you know if I figure anything out (:

Comment: thanks so much for your help!  Please do let me know if you find anything out, it really shouldn't be forcing me to create a db... I'm not finding any info but I'm gonna keep searching!

Comment: GiH: The tutorial probably doesn't cover installing the sqlite3-ruby gem because the author already has it installed. If you don't want to use a database, revert the settings in config/database.yml to sqlite3 and install the sqlite3-ruby gem.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks!!!!  Your right, he does a gem list in the beginning and I noticed sqlite3-ruby is there.  The funny thing is, when I go to my database.yml file, the comment says that gem install sqlite3-ruby is not required on OS X Leopard, so this shouldn't be necessary.  I guess RVM tripped things up.  But installing sqlite did solve this for me, FINALLY! I can now get to playing around with rails :-)

Comment: This brings up another question... what other necessary gems could I be missing since I'm using RVM?

Comment: GiH: i don't think you'd be missing any more gems. As long as you've got Rails and sqlite3-ruby installed I think you're set. Good luck, and if you need any more help keep asking!

Answer (score 0):

Don't access it through passenger, launch it using `ruby script/server` and check out the error it throws there. Generally those errors are way more descriptive than Passenger because Passenger is probably running your application using the `production` environment.

Comment: well i don't think it should make a difference, because I set it to run in development mode with the passenger preference pane.  And sure enough, I got the same errors.  I opened up the log as per Mark Quezada's comment, and the log shows the same errors that I got via passenger/apache.  The first thing it threw at me was a sqlite3 error.  I have not yet installed mysql (which I will), does it need to be installed for this to work?  I thought that I shouldn't need it to get this stuff to work since I'm not working with models yet. I'm going to update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ryan, do you need to Ruby 1.8.7?  Why don't you install the latest 1.9.2 and Rails 3?  I have the same environment and so far no problems.  Here is a link for installing everything you need.  Let me know if it helped! http://amerine.net/2010/02/24/rvm-rails3-ruby-1-9-2-setup.html
Salud!